# How to make a this specific Pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am having a problem with patterns.

I have string like this:

```
string1 = "27.86.80.76.83.45.66.71.80.45.76.68.80.45.67.97.108.108.45.84.105.116.45.77.97.114.105.111"
```

The strings appear in the middle of one file, with different lengths.

For instance I am reading a file line by line and I need to know if the line has this pattern.

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: And how do the other lines look like?

Comment: The other lines can have any type of letters or number.
I only need to grab the ones with a pattern similar to the one in string1

Comment: By "this pattern" do you mean groups of digits separated by `.`?  Lines starting with `27`?  Lines where the sum of the digits is prime?  What about `12.34.56`?  Should that match, or do you need to match exactly 28 number groups?  What about a line `12.34 45.67`?  Is that a match?  Two matches?  Et cetera.

Comment: griffin definitely pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two different ways to go about this:

1. Build a parser - much work, but very flexible and possibly best performance (depending on implementation)
2. Use a regular expression. In your case this could be something like `(\d{2,3}\.)+\d{2,3}` (shortest string matched should be `"111.11"`)

Comment: Yes, you were right. My problem was with the pattern. I always have problems with them.

Comment: Be careful, I missed SO kicking my \ before the . at first, just now corrected it.